# Subsetting a matrix on the basis of a list of some of the column names

Tags: r, matrix

Let's say there is a matrix - 'mat' which has 115 columns.

There is another matrix - 'res_mat' which has a column having 38 column names of the previous matrix 'mat'.

I want to create a third matrix - 'fin_mat' which will be a subset of the first matrix 'mat' having the columns which are stored as values in the column of the second matrix 'res_mat'.

Or in other words, I have a list of column names which is stored in a variable. How can I create a subset of the first matrix containing the columns which are stored in a variable?

Comment: Please review [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use the dplyr package with the functions "select" and "one_of". One_of allows to select columns based on their names (in a string format).

Here is a simple example with the iris table, in which I extract the columns names "Sepal.Length" and "Sepal.Width".

```
library(dplyr)

mat1 <- iris

mat2 <- data.frame(names = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")) %>%
  mutate(names = as.character(names))  #make sure the names are characters

results <- mat1 %>% select(one_of(mat2$names))
```

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't seem very difficult. If I understand your question correctly, something like this will do it.

```
# First make up some matrix
mat <- matrix(1:24, ncol = 6)
colnames(mat) <- paste0("Col", 1:6)

# These would be the columns to keep
res_mat <- matrix(c("Col1", "Col3", "Col4"), ncol = 1)

fin_mat <- mat[, res_mat[, 1]]
fin_mat
```

Comment: Hello
Thanks for your response. However, it is not giving me the desired result. 

The expected result is 
  Col 1 - "A"
  Col 3 - "C"
  Col 4 - "D"

However, what it is giving me is 
  Col 1 - "A"
  Col 2 - "B"
  Col 3 - "C"

Hope you get it.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done pretty easily. In the code below, I ma creating a dataframe `mat` and another one `res_mat`. `mat` has the data and `res_mat` has a single column named- `select_these_columns`. the `mat` dataframe has 10 columns named a,b,c,d,e...,j. the `select_thes_cols`column of `res_mat` has five rows with entries a,b,c,d,e. ALl that needs to be done is pass the `res_mat$select_these_cols` to `mat`

```
a <- (matrix(rnorm(1000), nrow = 100, ncol = 10))
mat <- as.data.frame(a)
names(mat) <- letters[1:10]
res_mat <- data.frame(x = letters[1:5])
names(res_mat) <- 'select_these_cols'
fin_mat <- mat[res_mat$select_these_cols] # subsetting operation
```

Comment: Hello
Thanks for your response. However, it is not giving me the desired result. 

The expected result is 
  Col 1 - "A"
  Col 3 - "C"
  Col 4 - "D"

However, what it is giving me is 
  Col 1 - "A"
  Col 2 - "B"
  Col 3 - "C"

Hope you get it.